# Outlet making sci-fi sound when lamps in room turned on or off

Tags: electrical

Several lamps (different types plugged into different outlets) & my ceiling fan/light now make a sci-fi sound (like from a space ship in a movie) for 3 or 4 seconds. One lamp makes the sound when turned off, the other when turned on. The lights seem to be just as bright & don’t flicker, they just make the strange sound. Either going on or off. Any ideas?

Last night I discovered I t’s not the lamps making the sound, it’s an outlet. The 2 lamps aren’t plugged into the same outlet, but the sound is definitely coming from that outlet. Last night I unplugged one of those scent dispensers that use oil thru a slightly heated tubular sponge, & that set off the spaceship sound too. We took a video of the sound happening when I turn on the lamp that’s plugged into that outlet. I’d attach the video, but this website seems to only accept photos.
To sum up, this 1 outlet makes a sound like I’d expect from a spaceship when either the lamp that’s plugged into it is turned on, a lamp plugged into an outlet 10’ away on another wall is turned off, when scent dispensers are unplugged from that outlet, & occasionally when the ceiling fan is turned off. The other day it made that sound with no one touching anything electrical in that room, but it may have been responding so something being turned on or off in the room below it. The switched are all standard & each of the lamps has different types of bulbs.

Comment: What make and model is the ceiling fan, and what make and model of bulbs are in the light fixtures?

Comment: What kind of bulbs do they have in them?

Comment: Do you have standard light switches, or some type of "smart" switches?

Comment: Sounds like a spaceship in an old movie, or in a new movie? They sound different.